# Having trouble with an Ada declaration "at 0 range 18..20"

Tags: variable-assignment, ada, variable-declaration

I'm having trouble with this variable declaration:

```
Code_Length at 0 range 18..20;
```

I'm familiar with constraints, but the `at 0` is what's giving me fits, and I can't find any working examples online anywhere else.

If I had to guess (and I'm totally guessing), the `at 0` initializes the value to `0`, then the constraint is enforced on any subsequent assignment operation.  But I can't find anything to verify that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not a variable declaration, that's a [representation clause](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-5-1.html#I5021) for a field of a record. Whatever record declaration you excerpted that from has a field named "Code_Length". And this representation clause indicates that the storage for it (3 bits) will be offset 0 bytes from the start of whole record's storage, and occupy bits 18 through 20.

Providing more contextual code would help the explanation.

Comment: Excellent explanation; thank you.  I would vote you up if I could.